# Aperiodic monotile without reflections?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, plane-geometry, tiling, aperiodic-tiling

The recently discovered amazing aperiodic monotile (or "einstein") of [David Smith, Joseph Samuel Myers, Craig S. Kaplan, and Chaim Goodman-Strauss](https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.10798) tiles the plane only if reflections of the monotile are allowed. Is there hope of modifying their construction to produce an aperiodic monotile that tiles the plane without the need for reflected tiles?

Comment: Would a shape count if there were periodic tilings of $\mathbb{R}^2$ by it, but every such tiling used tiles related by a reflection?

Comment: @RosieF Interesting question. What's an example of a monotile (which may or may not tile the plane non-periodically) with such a property?

Comment: [Doris Schattschneider](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Allendoerfer/1979/0025570x.di021103.02p0247f.pdf) shows families of pentagons which tile, and marks tiles that are "flipped". [Michael Rao](https://arxiv.org/abs/1708.00274) is an updated,  more technical paper. [Joseph Myers](https://www.polyomino.org.uk/mathematics/polyform-tiling/) has stats on suitable polyforms. Each link in the "isohedral" & "anisohedral" columns links to a file of shapes which tile but not by only translation & 180 degree rotation. Some tile but only with reflection.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The same authors have [just released a preprint](https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.17743) claiming a positive answer to this question.

EDIT:  Here is a picture of the reflection-free aperiodic monotile:

[image: Figure 1.1 from the paper]

More visualizations and other data are available at [this web page of one of the authors](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/%7Ecsk/spectre/).

Comment: NIce. If I understand correctly, this paper provides examples of the type suggested in [Rosie F's comment above](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/443525/aperiodic-monotile-without-reflections/447841#comment1145318_443525) as well as examples satisfying a stricter aperiodicity criterion.